# Downloading through address bar PHP

Tags: php

When I type in the following file path the file downloads

```
http://localhost/BookStore/download.php?file=books/feedback.pdf
```

I don't want this to happen, the user should only be able to download the file after a purchase occurs, if they use this method then they get the file for nothing.

Below is the code for my **download.php file**

```
<?php
function downloadFile($file,$speed=1024){
if (file_exists($file)) {
    if(is_dir($file)){return 'isdir';}
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));

    ob_clean();
    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    $chunksize=(sprintf("%u", filesize($file))/$speed);

    set_time_limit(0);
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
    die;
}else{return false;}
return;
}

    if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
        $file = $_GET['file'];
    }

    $result = downloadFile($file);

    if ($result == FALSE) {
        echo "Sorry, file does not exist.";
    }

?>
```

Is there any type of validation that can be used to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why is there a file before the purchase? Or is it the file they are purchasing? You should add a check if they have purchased it.

Comment: It is the file that they are purchasing, this download link only appears in their account after a purchase has taken place, however if you type in the adddress stated at the top it bypasses the whole purchase aspect of the system.

Comment: You need to implement authentication and authorization. You should already have at least some of that implemented  in other pages (otherwise you won't be able to run your shopping basket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they purchase a book set a session variable such as

```
$_SESSION[$book] = true;
```

or an array of books(for mutiple purchases)

```
$_SESSION['books] = $books;
```

And then reference this in a check within your function

```
if (file_exists($file) && isset($_SESSION[$file])) { // for a single book
```

or

```
if (isset($_SESSION['books']) && file_exists($file) && isset($_SESSION['books'][$file])) { // for an array of books
```

This is relatively untested but should give you a good start.

Comment: I had a more complete answer but as it was put on hold .... You can always message me if you want another example. I have a wordpress shop plugin so I had to deal with the same situation.

Comment: Would you be able to show me your example Christophe? Thanks